Changing website host but keeping mail server
I am newbie and facing a problem which you experienced folks can help.

My website abc.com is hosted with provider.
mx records are pointing to root domain (0 abc.com)
mail.abc.com is CNAME and pointed to abc.com.
if i type mail.abc.com in browser, it opens abc.com
I have made a website in my home server and want to use it for website only and want to keep mail with hosting provider.
SPF records have some other ip addresses which are different from my website ip. (like website ip is xxx.xxx.xxx.145 but spf records are xxx.xxx.xxx.218 and xxx.xxx.xxx.87)

How to proceed with this? I get this so far (which may be absolutely wrong):
I should point mail.abc.com to old website ip (or ip addresses mentioned in spf?)
Then point website A record to home server ip Will this work?

Either show us your DNS records or tell us the domain so we can see them ourselves - your description of how you configured them is inaccurate and misleading. Apex records are OK for MX and TXT (e.g. SPF and DMARC etc). The A record should only ever be used for redirecting HTTP[S] to a prefixed hostname. NEVER provide services on the apex record. NEVER have cnames pointing back to the apex.

To get the DNS updated, change mail.abc.com to an "A" record with the IP address of your mailserver (ie whatever the current value is for abc.com).
You will then be free to change abc.com and www.abc.com to the new address, and the MX record will correctly resolve so mail will continue.
There is a lot of nuance with SPF and the ideal answer on how to configure it depends on how you are using email - but hopefully the following is useful -
If one of the parts of the SPF record includes the word "mx" then that record likely covers your current use.  If you don't have the word "mx" in the record, you may want to add it - it can't hurt and could help in some setups.   You probably want to leave the existing ip address records - these are likely used by your hosting provider to actually send email.  (Either additional IPs on the same mail server, or more likely your web server is configured with a basic mail server which relays all email on to your hosting providers actual mail server.  It might be worth asking your hosting provider to clarify this - and also asking if they should be replaced with an "include" record - which is a more flexible way of doing things)

I changed the settings but not cpanel is not receiving mails. I can send mails and they are received by recipient.
mx record is 0 abc.com. and i haven't changed anything in spf records.
What can be issue and how to rectify it?

What is your domain name?

MX record needs to be changed to mail.abc.com   (and mail.abc.com needs to additionally have an A record associated with your mail server - ie the old IP address of the web hosting)

My domain name is: kuntalfoods.com.
I have now changed mx to mail.kuntalfoods.com and pointed mail.kuntalfoods.com to old ip of web hosting. I will wait for few hours and then check again,

unable to receive any mail from Gmail etc. I can send mail though,

kuntalfoods.com is using mx?.zoho.in as its MX records and does not have a mail.kuntalfoods.com record.  This means either thats a different domain to the one in question, you have made subsequent changes or you are manipulating a nameserver which is being ignored.

The mail was not working and i had to switch to zoho mail as last resort. But i have similar domain lawnagari.com (its emails are not important at the moment)on same server. I am working on this so that if i can solve this, i will implement the fix on kuntalfoods.com. everything is same,, server is also same, ip addresses are also same. So can you please check this domain (lawnagari.com)

@DushyantVerma You need to start by changing mail.lawngari.com to an A record (presumably with a value of 103.117.212.145), and then change the MX record for lawngari.com to mail.lawngari.com - Once you have done this you can change lawngari.com to its new IP address.
